# Will or will be?

Tags: grammar, future-tense

I am studying Oxford Practice Grammar Book. I have seen this sentence below. Can we use **"will be"** instead of **"will"** in this sentence?

> The meeting **will** start at half past seven.

Comment: There's also a related question asked years ago on ELU (before ELL was created) - [Correct usage of “will be” vs. “will”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/88253/correct-usage-of-will-be-vs-will)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a word, yes, if you mean can you write the sentence as:

*The meeting will be starting at half past seven*

The sentence above implies that the meeting will be happening shortly, whereas the sentence you have posted could be used for a meeting tomorrow.

Hope this helps!